# How to integrate a 3D function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, integral

I am writing a script that allows one to perform specific mathematical operations that involve integrals. For single integrals, I use `scipy.integrate.quad`. But there are cases where I want something to perform triple multivariable integrals like the following:

[image]

For the most part, there shouldn't be more than 3 variables, and I'm willing to work with something that doesn't go beyond triple integrals. Does anyone know any package, function or even script that could allow me to solve something like the equation shown?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Did you look at [scipy.integrate.tplquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html)? Note that the accuracy might be quite low. And when you increase the grid size, things can get very slow.

Answer (score 5):

Scipy's `integrate` module has [`scipy.integrate.dblquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html) and [`scipy.integrate.tplquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html#scipy.integrate.tplquad), which are very similar to the `quad` function you're already using, but allow double/triple integration.

To solve the equation shown, you could do something like the following:

```py
from scipy import integrate

f = lambda x, y, z: ... # Some function to integrate
x1 = lambda y, z: ...   # Lower boundary for x
x2 = lambda y, z: ...   # Upper boundary for x
y1 = lambda z: ...      # Lower boundary for y
y2 = lambda z: ...      # Upper boundary for y
z1 = 0
z2 = 1

integral = integrate.tplquad(f, z1, z2, y1, y2, x1, x2)
print(integral)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I haven't heard/used those yet. This definitely solves my problem.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! :) @A.Fattal